# Paypal log customers transactions

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am working on a web app which will allow small businesses to track their income. I would like a user of the app to register their paypal account and then paypal inform my software when they have received a payment from one of their customers so it can be logged - is this at all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) will do exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you happen to be using WordPress [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-ipn/) will get you up and running very quickly.  If not, but you are using PHP, you might be interested in [this basic solution](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-ipn-template).

Comment: No on wordpress but using php so will have a look at that thanks!